# How can i display wath i am searching in a theme

Tags: themes, search

How can i display wath i am searching in a Search Theme.

Ex: I search for Keword : Battleship

Result :

Your results retrive (3 posts) with the subject Battleship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to your template's search.php - somewhere before the loop:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
echo 'Your results retrive ('.$wp_query->found_posts.' posts) with the subject '.get_search_query().'.';
?>
```

If search.php does not exists in your template's directory, either copy archive.php (if it does not exists too, copy index.php - see [template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)) and rename it to search.php or insert following code, again before the loop, right into archive.php or index.php respectively:

```
<?php
if ( is_search() ){
    global $wp_query;
    echo 'Your results retrive ('.$wp_query->found_posts.' posts) with the subject '.get_search_query().'.';
}
?>
```

Comment: way the post get - ?

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality probably because it is a block of code with no explanation, even if the solution works. If you could provide a description of what the code does it would make a better answer.

Comment: Sorry for that - I've improved the answer...